# 0x80131904 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity

Using the Microsoft.Net v4.0 SqlClient connectivity built-in to Microsoft.Net via the `System.Data.SqlClient` assembly, a particular machine cannot connect to a particular set of servers.  When connections are attempted, the following error is thrown:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.SNIWritePacket(SNIHandle handle, SNIPacket packet, UInt32& sniError, Boolean canAccumulate, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WriteSni(Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.WritePacket(Byte flushMode, Boolean canAccumulate)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsLogin(SqlLogin rec)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo,String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at ConsoleApplication1.Module1.Main()
```

I can connect from other machines to the same target server using the same binary without issue.  I can also connect from the problematic server if I recompile the binary against Microsoft.Net v2.0.

The target server is configured to audit failed logins, however no failures are logged in the SQL Server errorlog as a result of this issue - I *can* cause an audit entry if I login with an invalid SQL Server login just to be certain the auditing is working.

The code I'm using to test this issue is:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim bUseSSL As Boolean = False

        If My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Contains("/SSL") Then
            bUseSSL = True
        End If

        If bUseSSL Then
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption enabled")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Encryption disabled")
        End If

        Dim cb As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        cb.ApplicationName = "SqlClientTest"
        cb.DataSource = "<server_name_here>"
        cb.IntegratedSecurity = True
        cb.Encrypt = bUseSSL
        'cb.TrustServerCertificate = True
        cb.NetworkLibrary = "dbmssocn"

        Try
            Using sqlconnection As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(cb.ConnectionString)
                Try
                    sqlconnection.Open()
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to " & cb.DataSource)
                    Dim sqlcommand As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT @@SERVERNAME;", sqlconnection)
                    Dim sqlreader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader
                    While sqlreader.Read
                        Console.WriteLine(sqlreader.GetString(0))
                    End While
                    sqlreader.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(cb.ConnectionString)
                    Console.WriteLine("")
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
                End Try
                Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to quit.")
                Dim cki As ConsoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey
                While cki.KeyChar.ToString.ToLower <> "q"
                    cki = Console.ReadKey
                End While
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(cb.ConnectionString)
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Module
```

The same failure is logged regardless of the encryption setting, and regardless of the `TrustServerCertificate` setting.

Something appears to be forcing the .Net SqlClient v4.0 *on this machine* to use SSL even if I disable it via the connection string.

Any ideas what to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing Microsoft .Net Framework version 4.6.2 resolves this issue in our environment, and appears to be related to the issue presented in [this Microsoft Docs migration guide for .Net Framework 4.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.5-4.6#sqlconnectionopen-fails-on-windows-7-with-non-ifs-winsock-bsp-or-lsp-present).

All affected machines have .Net Framework Version 4.5 or 4.5.1, and have the VMware vSockets DGRAM and vSockets STREAM Base Service Providers through the vsocklib.dll that advertise non-IFS compliance.

Why this issue only appears when attempting connections to certain SQL Server 2016 instances remains an open question.